# Records have not been changed when I update. What's wrong with my WHERE clause?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update in my `previousrecords` table which has a foreign key of prisoner_id from `prisoner` table. A prisoner can have multiple previous records

This is my previousrecords design table:

[image: prevrecord]

update.php

```
  <?php

include "connect.php";
$idd =$_GET['id'];
$previous = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM previousrecords 
INNER JOIN prisoner ON prisoner.prisoner_id = previousrecords.prisoner_id 
WHERE previousrecords.prisoner_id = $idd") or die($connect->error);

$rows3 = $previous->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

   if(isset($_POST['update'])){
$p_ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['p_id']);
        $p_recordd = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["p_record"]);
        $p_triall = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["p_trial"]);
        $p_sentencee = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["p_sentence"]);
        $p_releasedd = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["p_released"]);
        $p_datetransferredd = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["p_datetransferred"]);
        $p_jailtransferredd = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["p_jailtransferred"]);


$update_prev = $connect->query("UPDATE previousrecords SET prevrecord = '$p_recordd' , 
prev_trialcourt = '$p_triall' , prev_sentence = '$p_sentencee' , datereleased = '$p_releasedd' , 
datetransferred = '$p_datetransferredd' , jailtransferred = '$p_jailtransferredd' 
WHERE prev_id = $p_ID") or die($connect->error);

        if($update_prev === TRUE){

                       echo "Successfully updated!";}
else{
echo "Failed to update";
} }?>

<form method = 'post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 <?php foreach ($rows3 as $row){
                $p_ID = $row['prev_id'];
                $p_record = $row['prevrecord'];
                $p_trial = $row['prev_trialcourt'];
                $p_sentence = $row['prev_sentence'];
                $p_released = $row['datereleased'];
                $p_datetransferred = $row['datetransferred'];
                $p_jailtransferred = $row['jailtransferred'];  

             echo "
             <tr>
                <input type = 'hidden' name = 'p_id' value ='$p_ID'></td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'p_record' value ='$p_record'></td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'p_trial' value ='$p_trial'></td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'p_sentence' value ='N/A' readonly></td>
                <td><input type = 'date' name = 'p_released' value ='$p_released'></td>
                <td><input type = 'date' name = 'p_datetransferred' value ='$p_datetransferred'></td>
                <td><input type = 'text' name = 'p_jailtransferred' value ='$p_jailtransferred'></td>
             </tr>";
            }
             ?>
             </table>

<input type = 'submit' name = 'update' value ='Save Changes'>
</form>
```

Here are my values:

[image: tablevalues]

If I update prisoner_id 1's prev_record to child abuse in prev_id 1 nothing happens, only the update works on the last row that has the same prisoner_id which is the prev_id 2

I'm expecting my table to look like this

[image: child]

I think the problem is with my WHERE clause. What should be in my WHERE clause?

Please excuse my code. This is for my school project only, these codes are what have been taught to us. I will study on how to avoid SQL injections and apply it soon

Comment: It's best to avoid using images to present important parts of your question. Why? For one thing, images can't be searched, making it harder for others to benefit from your question. For another, sometimes people answering questions like to try to run your queries on their own machines or in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) or [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/). Text, indented four spaces, is a good way to present code and data.

Comment: Where is your variable `$row3` set? Once you have updated your table you need to rerun whatever query sets `$row3` to see the result of the update.

Comment: I have edited my question @O.Jones

Comment: I suggest the following for this and future debugging:
to check whether it's a bug in your statement or a bug in the php code:
define a query variable first, echo (or log) it and then run the sql statement directly on the db:
$query='SELECT blabla form blabla...';
echo $query; // (or log($query) if you have a log and log method)
$statement->execute($query);
then you make a test on the frontend, copy & paste the sql statements produced, go into phpmyadmin, and run the statements in the sql field.

like this you can see if its a problem with the query itself or the values in the query...

Comment: @CaneloDigital I checked in phpMyAdmin if the values have changed and nothing has changed. I tried to remove the WHERE clause, it changed but all the rows have the same value even if I only update a single row

Comment: Where is this statement terminated? `if(isset($_POST['update'])) {`

Comment: @Kee:I really suggest that you check the queries and results of your DB queries. Make a kind of a log, where these queries are printed out completely. copy the query, and check in phpmyadmin if it gives you the results you expect, or an error. On one specific example. If the results are wrong, recheck your query. If the results are right, recheck the code.

OH PD: I noticed something essential: You first call the join and data to display, then have the if ... update clause... so even if you try to change values, you first grab the display values from the DB and then change the DB...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed something essential: You first call the join and data to display, then have the if ... update clause... so even if you try to change values, you first grab the display values from the DB and then change the DB... So you will anyway show old data. A refresh though would bring the new data up.

THE OTHER THING WHICH IS ALSO WRONG is that if a prisoner has several entries, they are all showed in one form, with always the same form field names. The for each loop should be outside the form so you create a form for every single entry to change.

The way you have it at the moment, when the form is sent, there can be 4 or 5 $_POST['p_id'], $_POST["p_record"], etc... So most probably the first ones would be ignored and just the last entry would be updated in the DB. (If you would check the queries as I mentioned) you probably would hav seen that issue. 
There seems to be no error in your where clause, but in the HTML code which sets up only one form instead of one form for every prisoner's entry...

I really suggest that you check the queries and results of your DB queries. Make a kind of a log, where these queries are printed out completely. copy the query, and check in phpmyadmin if it gives you the results you expect, or an error. On one specific example. If the results are wrong, recheck your query. If the results are right, recheck the code. This is classical debug situations for DB calls, you would have noticed the same things I'm telling you here, that something's pretty wrong, less with the DB querys but more with the secuence of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have two MySQL operations in your code.

This is the first.

```
$previous = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM something
      WHERE something = $idd") or die($connect->error);
$rows3 = $previous->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

This is the second.

```
$update_prev = $connect->query("UPDATE previousrecords SET something=something... 
     WHERE $p_ID = something") or die($connect->error);
```

The thing is, you run your first operation *before* you run your second one. So, the information you render to your web page with

```
 <?php foreach ($rows3 as $row){
               $p_ID = $row['prev_id']; ...
```

shows the state of your tables **before** the update. Therefore, it looks like the update didn't work.  But it probably did.

Run your SELECT after your UPDATE.

Comment: I always check in my phpMyAdmin if changes have been made but still nothing @O. Jones

Comment: what should be in my WHERE clause if for example I update the row in prev_id 1, my prev_id is auto increment. Is it wrong that I get the value of the prev_id of each row in forearch loop and use it in my WHERE clause?

Comment: I have changed my WHERE clause to $p_ID = prev_id. Update only works on the last row in every the same prisoner_id. Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

for more easy you can use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

example:

```
$product_name = '52 inch TV';
$product_code = '9879798';
$find_id = 1;

$statement = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE products SET product_name=?, product_code=? WHERE ID=?");

//bind parameters for markers, where (s = string, i = integer, d = double,  b = blob)
$statement->bind_param('ssi', $product_name, $product_code, $find_id);
$results =  $statement->execute();
if($results){
    print 'Success! record updated';
}else{
    print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
}
```

please read the documentation